# Is there a bulk email app that integrates with Gmail Contacts?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'd like to send bulk email to Groups in my Gmail Contacts. I'd like the email to be addressed to people by their first names. Is this possible? Do I need to use an app that integrates with Gmail Contacts for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for [apps that offer newsletters for Google Apps](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?orderBy=rating&query=newsletters), for example [MailChimp](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=3525+5361236203077141107). As far as I know most of them use the contacts in your Google Apps account, but that might be something to check for.